# PHP How to protect the information from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how can I prevent give access to other people's information.

I mean that I have a form, which can be editable.

When person clicks on Edit button, he instantly redirects to the next page:

```
bla-bla-bla/edit.php&id=1337
```

The problem is that I can just go in the address bar and put `&id=1337` to `&id=143` or `&id=1943` and still access the someone elses data.

This is the original code which is displaying and editing:

Sorry for my English and thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use allow editing values for the same id of the user.store it in session.dont pass it through via url.

Comment: `IF(SESSION.UID == GET.ID) { ALLOW EDITING } ELSE { NOT ACTUAL USER, DENY THEM }` (*pseudo code*)

Comment: Just another note: `elsif` must be before `else` and requires a condition. Also you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should put the session var outside the string; e.g:

Change:

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id' && owner = '$_SESSION['user']['username']' "
```

for:

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id' AND owner = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' "
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have an err on line when the 2nd elseif starts `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /bla-bla-bla/ on line 61`

Comment: Replace "} elseif {"  for "} if($row['id']) {" ? Or something that is meaningful for your logic.

Comment: That didn't worked for me. It started to displaying even a fatal err lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just make the page editable for the current user, you could even just do away with the entire ID in the URL.

Change your page so that it checks if you are logged in (by using your `$_SESSION` variable). If logged in, retrieve and later save the data based on a combination of the `$_SESSION['UserID']` and other `$_SESSION` variables to make sure the person is who they claim they are.

You won't need to add the `?id=123` in the URL at all this way.